# How to create Google Chart with lines (series) of different lengths?

Tags: google-visualization

How do I create a Google Line Chart that displays two or more lines, with a different number of data points in each series?

For instance, I want to create a chart with 2 lines, one showing the *expected* values over time and another showing the *actual* values over time. The date range and expected values are known in advance so I can fully graph them, but the actual values may not be fully known yet (e.g. the date range covers some dates in the future).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488724/google-charts-api-using-a-fixed-set-of-datapoints). The solution is to use `"_"` (or `"__"`, depending on the encoding of the data values) to indicate "no value".

For instance, one data series might be `10,7,3,1` and the other might be `10,6,_,_`.